# Start VirtualBox VM before login (at reboot)

Tags: 14.04, virtualbox, startup, autostart

I want my VM to start at reboot and before login. I put this script in `rc.local` file to be executed before login and start my VirtualBox VM:

```
sudo -H -u  myuser /usr/bin/VBoxManage startvm "MyOS"
```

If I execute the file directly via terminal:

```
sudo /etc/rc.local
```

My VM will start correctly, but when reboot the OS nothing happens. What's wrong with that?

I tried to follow the instructions in this post:
[How to start Virtual box machines automatically when booting?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/404665/how-to-start-virtual-box-machines-automatically-when-booting) but it's not working for me because I don't have any `/etc/vbox` folder on my `Ubuntu 14.04` using `VirtualBox 4.3.10_ubuntu r93012`