# Autostart of VirtualBox VM with root-permissions

Tags: 14.04, permissions, virtualbox, scripts, autostart

Situation is the following: I'm having a Ubuntu14.04 LTS with VirtualBox installed. There is at least one VM that should start at the startup of ubuntu.

Since I have configured port-forwarding including port 80 for the VM I need root-permissions for the user executing the VM.

I have created a user "vboxrunner" that should run the VM. In the meantime I have added this user to the group "root".

I have found this thread (and similar ones) that I used to configure my system:
https://askubuntu.com/a/404695/457544

- I have created the configuration /etc/default/virtualbox
- I have setup a /etc/vbox/autostart.cfg
- I set permissions for /etc/vbox
- I set the autostartdbpath
- And I enabled autostart for the VM
- I was required to add the vboxautostart-service manually since it was not part of my system. The statement *sudo service vboxautostart-service restart* does not work but I can execute *sudo service vboxautostart-service start* as well as *sudo service vboxautostart-service stop* but both without any result!

I'm encountering some issues ... I'm not a expert on ubuntu. So I think I make something wrong. Current state is the following:

- If I'm logged in as "vboxrunner" and start the VM with *sudo vboxmanage startvm MyVM* it works.
- Doing it without *sudo* there is an error that the registered machine MyVM could not be found.
- I have added the root-user as well as the vboxrunner-user to the group "vboxusers".
- Using the statement *service vboxautostart-service start* does not start the VM. As a result the VM does not start at boot of the ubuntu-system.

What is required to start the VM with root-permissions at startup of ubuntu? What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I solved it editing the file: */etc/rc.local*

Adding the line *vboxmanage startvm MYVM --type headless* make it working fine.