# Headless Ubuntu into VirtualBox virtual machine

Tags: boot, virtualbox, desktop-environments, headless

I want to run just any regular image set up in VirtualBox. Is it possible to run a virtual image/desktop with VirtualBox before the Ubuntu desktop environment loads?

Comment: Try again that makes no sense.

Comment: Something [like this](https://askubuntu.com/a/404695/1222991), perhaps? I've not checked if this answer works with a modern release of Ubuntu, but it may get you started.

Comment: So basically you want to drive the car before you start it.

Comment: I'll take that as a no

Comment: Theoretically, yes. The X system (or Wayland if you use that) is started before the user is logged in. Then the graphic display system kicks in, showing the login page. Then only after the user logs in, the user's DE is started. So I suppose that you could use the graphics of the system without being logged in, but I have no Idea why you would want that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not a good idea to run a virtual image/desktop with VirtualBox before the Ubuntu desktop environment loads. VirtualBox is a GUI application in Ubuntu which requires a desktop environment to be loaded in order to be able to run it in a user friendly way.